Chat with Sql: I want to show query result table in the form of dataframe in my web app and also make chart
The code generates a SQL query, executes it, and stores the result in a variable named result. I want to display this result as a data frame, including the column names from the original query. I am using the latest version of every library.
#To load the database
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

def load_db(db_name):
    db=SQLDatabase.from_uri(f"sqlite:///Chinook.db")
    return db

# to create sql query chain to execute queries
def chain_create(db):
    llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo")
    chain = create_sql_query_chain(llm, db)
    return chain

# To create another chain to answer the queries based on the data retrieved by querying

def sql_infer(db,chain,user_question):
    sql_query=chain.invoke({"question":user_question})
    result=db.run(sql_query)
    print(result)
    print(type(result))

    st.code(sql_query)
    st.write(result)

    answer_prompt=PromptTemplate.from_template(
        """Given the following user question, corresponding SQL query, and SQL result,
            generate a proper reply to give to user

            Question:{question}
            SQL Query:{query}
            SQL Result:{result}
            Answer:"""
    )
    llm_model=ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo")
    llm=LLMChain(llm=llm_model,prompt=answer_prompt)
    ans=llm(inputs={"question":user_question,"query":sql_query,"result":result})
    return ans["text"]

Can anyone give me a hint on how I should approach this?
